# Best way to send client designs

Tags: website-design, client-relations

I have several design ideas wich I want to send to a client, although the easiest way is to send them an email with the images attached then get feedback and send another email is there an easier way?
Is there a good cloud-based system where I can manage ideas and get feedback?

Comment: Heavily depends on the client, the kind of job, and yourself. I'm thinking this is very opinion-based. Besides, I don't think you want to be adding their ideas live. Before you know it, you're the Photoshop monkey and they're the art director.

Comment: I just want an easier way to send designs and ideas and get feedback. I have considered options like a shared drive folder but its hard for them to add feedback

Comment: How's about a meeting? As, in IRL, in the flesh, in realspace? Scary, I know :)

Comment: I have three client meetings 80% of the time. Start, middle and when its finished. In the mean time you can just upload them to google drive and let them review it there. I dont see why its hard to add feedback like this?

Comment: Talking to real people, nah. Sadly I work with a lot of holiday companies based everywhere and at 15 I'm not flying out to meet them. This is also why calling them is a pain because of timezones. I guess I was dreaming of a perfect world where there was some cloud based software to manage this sort of thing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: There is *some* software that can help in this regard. I'd have a look at Basecamp if I were you, which is used to manage projects online. You can up- and download images, and have to-do lists and conversations.

Comment: Just looked, seems great thanks I will give it a try

Comment: Dropbox/Box are two other useful file storage/sharing sites. They don't have integrated feedback (AFAIK) but they're pretty good. Just out of curiosity - would you be interested if I said I could develop something like this for you?

Comment: Yes, but the problem would be price, I would not be able to afford any custom solution but you have given me an idea. I might try and make a google apps script to create comments though google docs and be able to organise revisions ect.

Comment: You already can add comments using google docs. There is a "comment" button

Comment: I know but not easily to images, it just puts the whole image as a comment not where you want it.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [ProofHQ](http://www.proofhq.com) for a long time now and it's been a blessing since then.
Jump there and check all the features it has for handling designs, versions, comments, revisions, approvals, everything cloud based and seriously thought through. Haven't found any other option that gets this good, to be honest. My clients love it.

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of web-based design version control products recently, though most of them seem to have been discontinued (LayerVault was a good one), as it clearly isn't a service enough people are willing to pay for.

[Pixelapse](https://www.pixelapse.com/) is another option, though it was acquired by Dropbox in January last year – they said they'd continue support for a year, which means it's on borrowed time.

Which leads me to Dropbox. If you use Dropbox, you can send your client a link to a PDF or image file and have them [leave comments on the file itself](https://blogs.dropbox.com/dropbox/2015/04/commenting-now-available/). You might want to set up a shared 'Proofs' folder for your client, and save your proofs into it (named *'YYMMDD Project Proof#*' or something similar). Dropbox also lets you add an 'expiry' to a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.wetransfer.com/
No need to sign up. Its very secure. I have been using it for few years now. You can send upto 2 gb for free. The UI of this site is good as well.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Sketch (which, if you're doing web design, you should be.), [Zeplin](https://zeplin.io) was designed just for this reason. Its built for designers to send their work over to developers and/or clients for feedback and to send into production.

If you're not using Sketch. You can send JPGs of your work and ask your client to install [Skitch](https://evernote.com/skitch/?var=c) to annotate screenshots of your work.

Comment: Skitch will only be available for Mac for that would only work if your clients are using a Mac.